# Composer update PHP warning -- related to new package? (Laravel4)

Tags: php, json, laravel-4, composer-php

I just added a new package to my composer.json in Laravel4 --

```
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.4.*"
```

and on doing command line "composer update", I got this warning:

```
PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  ' in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php on line 118
```

which I've never seen before on all previous Composer updates, which have all been flawless. In fact, the exact same message appeared 6 times, so I'm assuming that this reflects multiple attempts by Composer.

Here's my "require" array in composer.json:

```
    "require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.4.*"
},
```

Am I correct in assuming that this relates to bad code in the package I've added, and not something on my end? The only change I made was to add the package to my composer.json file, and that's clearly not what the error message refers to. Thanks.

Comment: it is the last line in your "require" array, correct?

Comment: I think so -- I just edited my question to add the array. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the package out of your composer file, and then do:

```
composer update
```

Then, add a different package, if you need an example: use [Jefferey Way's laravel generator](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators):

```
"way/generators": "2.*"
```

which every laravel install should have. if it runs through correctly, post an issue on the conflicted packages github about the error.

I apologize that i cant give you an exact answer, but unit testing the conflicting package is outside the scope of the question

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful but now I'm even more perplexed -- I removed the dompdf package, but then when doing the composer update, I get exactly the same PHP error. Composer lives in my system in /usr/local/bin, so it's globally available. The path specified in the error message doesn't exist! I have absolutely no idea how to fix this. Thanks for any additional suggestions.

Comment: OK, I found the vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php file in Laravel. Here is line 118 -- I don't find anything obvious wrong with it, and I've never touched it before:     'Illuminate\\Auth\\Reminders\\RemindableInterface' => $vendorDir . '/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Reminders/RemindableInterface.php',

Comment: Remeber that when you call composer, its looking for composer.json. I've gotten burned on moments where it took me an hour to figure out that "file not found" was in reference to composer.json. Dont mess with the vendor files. its easier to just re-install laravel, than try to sift through that stuff